# How to get element position in hidden tab-panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a script that works fine if the tab-panel is not hidden, but I need to count position, width of the element without to do action with tab-panel display , because that script i use beyond tab-panel like only ".swipeTab".

P.S. Sorry for my English ...

For example:

```
<div class="tab-panel" style="display: none">
    <div class="swipeTab">
        <div class="swipeTab__list">
            <div class="swipeTab__item">TAB 1</div>
            <div class="swipeTab__item">TAB 2</div>
            <div class="swipeTab__item">TAB 3</div>
            <div class="swipeTab__item">TAB ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Part of script**

```
var target = $('.swipeTab__item'),
    list= $('.swipeTab__list');

position: function(target) {
        return {
            left  : $(target).position().left,
            right : parseInt($(list).outerWidth()) - parseInt($(target).position().left) - parseInt($(target).outerWidth())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Position doesn't really make sense when using `display: none`. The DOM is rendered without allocating space for the div. You can use `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: for me is not a solution , because where is tab-panel will be a "transparent space"